# variable value changing does not delay setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout

I am making a red light green light type game. Here is the part where the stoplight changes color:

```
var green = function() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() *5000 + 3000);
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(900, 580, 200, 100);
    green = true;
    setTimeout(red, r);
};
var red = function() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() *3000 + 2000);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(900, 580, 200, 100);
    green = false;
    setTimeout(green, r);
};
```

If I take out the variable green, then it works fine but I need it so the game knows when the player can and cant move. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You're trying to use "green" as a variable that holds a function *and* as a flag.  There's only one "green" variable however.  Maybe you want a variable called "isGreen" in addition to "green".

Comment: @techfoobar no, "red" seems OK; it's just the function. The "green" function gets obliterated however the first time "green" is called.

Comment: You are replacing `green` with a boolean, use other variable name for boolen like `is_green`

Comment: @Pointy - Ahh yes.. i misread the first boolean assignment as `red = true;` for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

You override the variable `green`.

Initially it is a `function`, and inside the `red` function, you assign `true` to it. That's the reason your `setTimeout(green,r);` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you instead of a Boolean value I assigned a new variable color to "green" or "red" depending on the function. This works thank you!

Comment: @JosephClark Great. If it helped you, then accepting the answer is the right thing to do :-)